# Create a formulary

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I need to create a formulary (A big number of formulas all on the same page) but I don't know which package(s) I have to use and I didn't found nothing on the web.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about this collection of formulas. E.g., should they all be left-aligned, centered, aligned on `=` signs, or aligned according to still a different criterion? Should the equations be numbered or unnumbered? Are all equations short, or will some need to be broken across two or even more lines?

Comment: Also, do you want them to be framed, or with a shaded background or whatever you might think of?

Comment: I would like to put as many equation as I can. I'm not interested about alignment or size. 
I need it for an exam where I can take only one sheet, so I don't really care about the appearance. Also I don't need borders, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A starting point could be something like this. Multiple columns on a landscape page. You can reduce the font size if needed, or modify the margins, or increase the number of columns.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol} % for multicols environment
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath, for math environments etc
\usepackage{geometry} % for defining margins etc
\geometry{
 margin=1cm,
 landscape
}
\allowdisplaybreaks % allow environments like gather and align to break across columns/pages
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
Some equation:
\begin{equation*}
a=b
\end{equation*}
Bunch of eqs:
\begin{gather*}
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
a=b \\
\end{gather*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]