# How to write a cheat sheet like this in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

I am self-studying mathematics and would like to write 'cheat sheets' for myself to memorise the contents of the books I have bought - summaries of the text and of the solutions to the exercises.

My handwriting is poor so I think I should write these summaries in LaTeX, and save them as PDF documents.

I am a beginner at using LaTeX and not sure which editor is best for the 'cheat sheet' style I am after, e.g.

https://rawgithub.com/daleroberts/math-finance-cheat-sheet/master/math-finance-cheat-sheet.pdf

I don't need the ability to do graphs just equations. 
I guess this has some element of desktop publishing?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You mean like this one of mine? http://ziga-lausegger.com/download/univerza/skripte/moderna_fizika/moderna_fizika-list_z_enacbami.pdf Or maybee this one as well: http://ziga-lausegger.com/download/univerza/skripte/astronomija/astronomija-list_z_enacbami.pdf

Comment: Yes exactly - much better examples than mine

Comment: Is it fine if I just give you source code as an answer? Because as you can imagine this is a big project...

Comment: Note that the editor is completely irrelevant, the best editor is the one you like best, and it has no influence on the output.

Comment: Completely off-topic: You should improve your hand writing. If you cannot read your own stuff, you have a real reason to do so.

Comment: Check these posts for some ideas: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911516/how-to-make-cheat-sheets-in-latex) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8827/preparing-cheat-sheets).

Comment: @user3203476: in your examples was given a [source](https://github.com/daleroberts/math-finance-cheat-sheet) for that example.  You can find the [input files](https://github.com/daleroberts/math-finance-cheat-sheet/blob/master/math-finance-cheat-sheet.tex) there. also:

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I agree with you.  Also I think, the Tags should be improved, what do you think?

Comment: @Jan (You didn't see the [edit summary I wrote when I edited](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/346652/4) did you.) If you can think of any better tags, just add them.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I missed to reload the page.  Sorry.  My true fault!  This suits better, I think.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all you need to set up the page in the header so that you can use as much space as you want - use geometry package like this or similarly:

```
\usepackage[
    total={130mm,277mm},
    top=0mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    left=0mm,
    marginparwidth=0mm,
    marginparsep=0mm,
    centering,
    includefoot]{geometry}
```

Then you need to set small font using `\scriptsize` and divide your page into three or more columns using `minipage` environment like this:

```
\begin{document}

\scriptsize

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.333\textwidth}
    ~
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.333\textwidth}
    ~
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.333\textwidth}
    ~
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Then you can use different mathematical environments (use packages `mathtools`, `amsmath`, `breqn`) inside each `minipage` (where i put `~`) like this:

```
\begin{align*}
    &~\smash{c_0 = 1/\sqrt{\varepsilon_0 \mu_0}}\\
    &\boxed{
    \begin{aligned}
    I &= \di e/ \di t\\
    \smash{[C]} &= \smash{[As]}\\
    \smash{[T]}&=\smash{[Ns/Cm]}
    \end{aligned}
    }~
\end{align*}
```

You can use `\boxed{}` environment to frame the equations. You will need to use `\smash{}` in order to minimize the vertical spacing of some equations in order not to get too big. Sometimes even `\clap{}` might come handy - it reduces horizontal spacing.

Inside the `align*` environment you can vertically align parts of equations with `&` which will appear one below the other. And you can do this in `aligned` environment as well.

Comment: Thank you.  I was very interested in the way, you produced the graphics of the spectrum on your last sheet.

Comment: If columns is all you need, then another possible approach would be `multicols`, as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344877/create-a-formulary/344888#344888 (Edit: oh, and `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so having both is a bit redundant.)

Comment: Torbjørn T. I don't know if usage of `multicols` is appropirate here... I am not sure if it is possible to adjust each column's width like with `minipage`?

Comment: I don't think it is, but you may not need that, so it depends on what your requirements are. Of course, for the more complex handwritten examples the OP first showed, `multicols` is not the right tool.

Comment: Or `flowfram` @TorbjørnT. I've actually used `minipage`s inside `multicols` columns for (TeX) cheat-sheets.

Comment: @cfr How did that work out?

Comment: @71GA It has worked well for a Biblatex cheat-sheet I wrote, so long as you don't try compiling it on OverLeaf. This is a shame because that's what I'm using to publish the files .... But I have to check - maybe they've updated their installation by now.

Comment: hi this works really well.  may I ask: how would you (1) add vertical lines between the 3 columns , and (2) a small line in between each align* blocks ?

Comment: It would be best if you open a new topic for this question. Extensive chat in comments should be avoided here. You need to put those vertical lines in between minipages.